# zsh 環境で pyenv global 3.7.4 に設定しても反映されない

Tags: python, pyenv, zsh

Macのターミナルでpyenv からPython3.7.4をインストールし、`pyenv global` でデフォルトに設定しようとしたものの2.7.16のままです。
下記の通り `pyenv version` で見てみるとセットされているようなのですが。

```
% pyenv version
3.7.4 (set by /Users/*******/.python-version)
```

OSをCatalinaにアップデートしているのでshellはzshなのですが、bashにするとpython3.7.4にちゃんとなります。ですがzshで使いたいので解決策が見つかりません。

### 追記

`echo $PATH | perl -ple 's/:/\n/g;'` の結果は以下の通りです。

```
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin /Library/Apple/bin
```

zsh再起動後、Python 2.xが動いてしまうようです。

```
% cat ~/.zshrc  
% export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" >> ~/.zshrc  
% export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc  
% eval "$(pyenv init -)" >> ~/.zshrc  
% python -V  
Python 3.7.4
```

再起動後

```
% python

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.16 (default, Aug 24 2019, 18:37:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: `echo $PATH | perl -ple 's/:/\n/g;'` の結果を貼ってもらえますか？

Comment: /usr/local/bin  
/usr/bin  
/bin  
/usr/sbin  
/sbin  
/Library/Apple/usr/bin  
/Library/Apple/bin

Comment: @cubick さんの言う通り、 ~/.zshrc か ~/.zshenv に `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` が含まれていないように見えます。

Comment: 含んだのですが、ターミナル再起動してPythonを打つとまた２系に戻ってしまいます。。

Comment: (zshの環境で) `python -V` でバージョンを確認しても 2.x のままでしょうか？

Comment: 念の為 `cat ~/.zshrc` と、先ほどの $PATH の結果を回答に追記してもらえますか。コメント欄だと厳しそうです。

Comment: 多分cubickさんが言うようにコマンドとして打っただけではその場限りなだけなのでちゃんとエディタでzshrcに書き込まなければいけないと思うのですがどうやってzshrcに書き込むのかがわからない状況です。VSCodeでファイルを探してもないしgoogleで検索しても思うようにヒットしないので、、、。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zsh で使用する場合には、`.zshenv` や `.zshrc` などに以下の設定を追加してください。

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout

> **Define environment variable `PYENV_ROOT`** to point to the path where pyenv repo is cloned and add `$PYENV_ROOT/bin` to your `$PATH` for access to the `pyenv` command-line utility.

(蛇足の追記)

「VScodeから `~/.zshrc` が見つからない」とのことですが、ファイル名がドット(`.`)から始まるものは通常だと **隠しファイル扱い** となり、ファイルの一覧には表示されない場合があります。

Macでファイラ(Finder)を使用している場合には、以下ページの方法を参考にしてみてください。

[Macで隠しファイル・隠しフォルダを表示する方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/TsukasaHasegawa/items/fa8e783a556dc1a08f51)

Comment: 打った画面ではちゃんと3.7.4になるのですが、ターミナルを再起動させるとまた２系に戻ってしまいます。。。

Comment: コマンドとして実行しただけではその場限りでしか反映されません。エディタで `~/.zshenv` や `~/.zshrc` を開いて回答に記載した 3行の設定を直接追記する必要があります。

Comment: すみません。どうすれば~/.zshrcにかきこめるのでしょうか？VSCodeでファイルを探しても出ないです。

Comment: @DJCowardice さん、スクリプトの**実行結果**を`.zshrc`に`>>`で追記するのではなく、 スクリプト**そのもの**を`.zshrc`にコピーアンドペーストしてください。

Comment: そのzshrcに書き込むにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？ターミナルにコピペするだけだと意味がないようですので、、

Comment: "VScode から ~/.zshrc が見つからない" 件について、対応方法を追記しました。

Answer (score 0):

自分も質問者様と、全く同じ問題にぶつかりました。
他の回答者様と同じ処理をやってから、最後に

```
source　~/.zshrc
```

を入力すれば、解決できました。

参考になれば幸いです。